# Find the set of values of $\lambda$ for which the equation $|x^2-4|x|-12|=\lambda$ has 6 distinct real roots

Tags: inequality

> Find the set of values of $\lambda$ for which the equation $|x^2-4|x|-12|=\lambda$ has 6 distinct real roots

**My Approach:**

$|x^2-4|x|-12|=\lambda$

*Case 1:*

$x^2-4|x|-12=\lambda$

- If $x\geq 0$
  $x^2-4x-12=\lambda\cdots(i)$
- If $x<0$
  $x^2+4x-12=\lambda\cdots(ii)$

*Case 2:*

$x^2-4|x|-12=-\lambda$

- If $x\geq 0$
  $x^2-4x-12=-\lambda\cdots(iii)$
- If $x<0$
  $x^2+4x-12=-\lambda\cdots(iv)$

Now, we know the equation has 6 distinct real roots. So either only 3 equations have real roots which are all distinct too, or, some roots are common. I don't now how to solve further and I need a hint to proceed.

Comment: Just sketch the graph of the function $|x^2-4|x|-12|$.  In particular identify all of the local mins and maxs and the behavior at $\pm \infty$.  Since the function is continuous with finitely many critical points, this will provide enough information to identify which values in the range are taken exactly $6$ times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\lambda$ must obviously be non-negative. Then assume

- $x\ge0$ and

  1. $x^2-4x-12-\lambda=0$. The roots are $x=2\pm{\sqrt{16+\lambda}}$, but only the $+$ sign is valid. For all $\lambda$, one root.
  2. $x^2-4x-12+\lambda=0$. The roots are $x=2\pm{\sqrt{16-\lambda}}$. They are both positive and distinct for $12<\lambda<16$.
- $x\le0$ and

  1. $x^2+4x-12-\lambda=0$. The roots are $x=-2\pm{\sqrt{16+\lambda}}$, but only the $-$ sign is valid. For all $\lambda$, one root.
  2. $x^2+4x-12+\lambda=0$. The roots are $x=-2\pm{\sqrt{16-\lambda}}$. They are both negative and distinct for $12<\lambda<16$.

In conclusion, for $12<\lambda<16$, there are three positive and three negative roots.

Comment: clearly the best answer at the moment, plotting shows (at best) that there are at least 6 roots but not that there are exactly 16 roots for these values of $\lambda$.

Comment: @Surb: I agree that graphical solutions are never complete and rigorous proofs. In this case, anyway, the function is piecewise quadratic and this might be used to bound the number of roots.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**
[image]

$$|x^2-4|x|-12|=\lambda$$

$$y=|x^2-4|x|-12|$$
$$y=\lambda$$
Answer: $$12<\lambda<16$$

Answer (score 3):

you can plot the $|x^2-4|x|-12|$

[image]

then you easy to find
$$12<\lambda<16$$